# How do I position the search box to my specs?

Tags: css, wordpress

I've got the search-form within a div but I can't seem to position it where I wan't. Using "top","bottom","left","right" commands aren't working. The command "margin: 0 auto;" centers the div on the x plane but not on the y plane. Anybody know why this is happening & how I can change it?

CSS

```
#box {
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
}
#postcode-search {
    height: 60px;
    width: 510px;
    border: 3px solid yellow;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

input#item-search.form-control {
    height: 50px;
    width: 450px;
    border: 1px solid #fd0e35;
    padding: 0px;
    top: 400px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
```

HTML

```
<div id="box">
    <div id="postcode-search">
        <?php get_search_form();?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want to position the form inside the `postcode-search` to the center both horizontal and vertically to the div `box` right?

Comment: That is correct, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `Flexbox`

```css
#postcode-search {
  height: 60px;
  width: 510px;
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div id="postcode-search">
    Search box
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That perfectly centred the search from inside the postcode-search div, thank you! But the postcode-search div still doesn't respond to me trying to reposition it to the center of the box div. Do you know how to change that too?

Comment: If they are both `height: 60px` you don't need css for `#box` but if box have some other height then you can do this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/300/

Answer (score 0):

```css
#box {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
}

#postcode-search {
  height: 60px;
  width: 510px;
  border: 3px solid yellow; 
  position: relative;
  text-align:center;
}

input#item-search.form-control {
  height: 50px;
  width: 450px;
  border: 1px solid #fd0e35;
  padding: 0px;
  top: 400px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}

#postcode-search > *{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div id="postcode-search">
    <form>
      <input id="item-search" class="form-control" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```